# H2oGPT - cannot import name 'set_seed'

Tags: h2o, openai-api

I'm stuck with H2oGPT, I can't let it run.

I am running on a Windows PC with

- 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz
- 32GB memory 64bit
- GPU Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050

I followed all the procedure described in the [H2oGPT Windows Installation Page](https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/blob/main/docs/README_WINDOWS.md).

This is the command I launch.

```
$ python generate.py --base_model='llama' --prompt_type=llama2 --score_model=None --langchain_mode='UserData' --user_path=./my_documents
```

This is the error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dulcin\Documents\Java\UltraGPT\h2ogpt\generate.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.gen import main
  File "C:\Users\dulcin\Documents\Java\UltraGPT\h2ogpt\src\gen.py", line 32, in <module>
    from utils import set_seed, clear_torch_cache, NullContext, wrapped_partial, EThread, get_githash, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_seed' from 'utils' (C:\Users\dulcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

My questions are:

1. Should I install "utils" seaprately?
2. Is my laynch command ok? ./my_documents right now only contains one text document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

pseudotensor commented 3 days ago •
Looks like you have a package "utils" installed and it's looking there instead of the local code.

Maybe try:

setenv PYTHONPATH=.:src:$PYTHONPATH

python generate.py ...

Here is the link to the same issue:  https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/issues/622#issuecomment-1666898436

Comment: Thank you. I also add that I solved this clash using a python virtual environment.